# PHP types for Twig in PHPStorm

Tags: templating, plugins

As this tip ([Twitter](https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/937866640275988481)) suggested we can use type hints for Twig in PHPStorm after installing Symfony Support plugin by utilizing its [PHPTypes feature](https://symfony2-plugin.espend.de/languages/twig/index.html#phptypes), for example putting:

`{# @var craft \craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable #}`

at the top of a template would auto-complete all properties and methods in `craft.abc` for us.

### Type hints for plugins?

How could we get auto-completion for plugin variables?

Let's have a look at the Imager plugin. It is accessible via `craft.imager`. If I put

`{# @var imager \aelvan\imager\variables\ImagerVariable #}`

at the top of the template the IDE actually auto-completes for me when I type `imager.abc`, however this obviously throws an error because Craft expects `craft.imager.abc`. But the IDE doesn't autocomplete `craft.imager.abc`.
I also tried

`{# @var craft.imager \aelvan\imager\variables\ImagerVariable #}`

which is *not working*.

### Ugly workaround

If I put `craft.imager` into a local variable the auto-completion is working:

```
{# @var imager \aelvan\imager\variables\ImagerVariable #}
{% set imager = craft.imager %}
{% imager.transformedImage(...) %}
```

Any hints? hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Craft Autocomplete](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-autocomplete), and it will do all of this for you automatically in PhpStorm:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-autocomplete